# Block Reward in Proof of Stake Concept

Tags: mining, proof-of-stake

I am doing some research on the PoS concept and it seems like validators in a PoS network are getting rewarded by receiving the tx fees of the blocks they are validating. However, most resources state that there is no block reward. Now I ask myself if in this case the total supply of the coin is fixed or if there is any other mechanism to increase the total supply of the coin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is an Ethereun forum:

Ethereum 2.0 proof of stake has inflation rewards for the validators that stake. [You can find more information about rewards ad the proof of stake structure in this blog post of mine](https://capitalgram.com/posts/ethereum-2.0-staking-and-stakewise/).